what's the solution to unsupported FEATURE_TELEPHONY_RADIO_ACCESS?
I want to use some public methods from Android TelephonyManager which requires FEATURE_TELEPHONY_RADIO_ACCESS.
However, as I checked it using package manager it shows that my device does not support that radio access. Do you guys have solutions to this issue?
